# Database connection timeout error in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, sidekiq

Currently am running backgroud jobs with sidekiq, while running its giving **"ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError".**

```
This is my current database.yml file,

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_production
  username: password
  password:
  host: app.domain.com
  pool: 25
```

This is is my sidekiq.yml file,

```
production:
    concurrency: 25
    timeout: 300
```

While running its giving connection timeout error

This error was am getting in the backgroud,

```
could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.82230675 seconds). The max pool size is currently 25; consider increasing it.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maximum number of connections allowed to your postgres database is 25. But you have set your concurrency for sidekiq as 25. So if you have all the concurrent threads for sidekiq running, you will not have any database connection available for your app server.

Either reduce the sidekiq concurrency or increase the pool size(I recommend increasing the pool size).

Postgres allows 100 concurrent connections by default

Comment: @vimsa Actually in sidekiq itself it was giving error. Is there any possibilty to increase database connection time from 5 seconds to 25 seconds. Did you checked the error message "could not obtain a database connection **within 5 seconds (waited 5.82230675 seconds)**"

Comment: change your `timeout:300` in `sidekiq.yml` to `timeout:1500`.

Comment: @SaravanaKumAr: Its not able to establish the connection within 5 seconds because it has reached its max connection.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections

Comment: @vimsa I had added that in sidekiq.yml. So i need to add timeout option into database.yml right?
Is there any problem in that. i mean if i added timeout to 300, Is it affect any other process?